# Facebook conversion tracking (fbq) with PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

How I can replace JS function `fbq('track', 'Lead', { ... })` through **PHP API SDK**?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/pixel

Comment: Facebook takes client-side data into account in their tracking, like which user is currently logged in to Facebook. Therefor it makes very little sense to try and do that server-side.

Comment: Have the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925859/facebook-pixel-events-call-from-server :(

Comment: Could that data be passed to PHP? Why is there even an FB conversion tracking API if one can not use it?